# Program Keeps Out Printing Both Messages

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, character

I have some code going on here, I'm trying to get the user to input a Letter, 
   Number, or a Symbol, I have them all working, but when I enter a Letter, it 
   outprints both the "You have entered a Letter" and "You have entered a 
   Symbol" But thing is, I never entered a Symbol in the first place, just a 
   Letter. Heres how it looks:

Enter a SINGLE character:

D

You entered a LETTER!

You entered a SYMBOL!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Java1304
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     new Problem();
  }
}

class Problem
{
    char letter;

    public Problem()
    {
        input();
        process();
        output();
    }

    void input()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

        out.println("Enter a SINGLE character:");
        letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }

    void process()
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(letter))
        {
            out.println("You entered a LETTER!");
        }
        if(Character.isDigit(letter))
        {
            out.println("You entered a NUMBER!");
        }
        if(!Character.isLetter(letter) || !Character.isDigit(letter))
      //else
            out.println("You entered a SYMBOL!");

    }

    void output()
    {
        out.println();
        out.println();
        out.println();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired behavior is not reflected in the code you wrote.  The statement `!Character.isLetter(letter) || !Character.isDigit(letter)` evaluates to true if either the character is not a letter OR not a number (as || is the logical operator for or).

Going back to your example, if you type "A", `Character.isDigit(letter)` evaluates to false, so `!Character.isDigit(letter)` evaluates to true, so `!Character.isLetter(letter) || !Character.isDigit(letter)` evaluates to true.

Based on your example, your if block could be better written as:

```
 if(Character.isLetter(letter)){
        out.println("You entered a LETTER!");
 } else if(Character.isDigit(letter)){
        out.println("You entered a NUMBER!");
 } else {
        out.println("You entered a SYMBOL!");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) strike again! The `||` is your culprit. It needs to be `&&` for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is true because `!Character.isLetter(letter)` is true. The `||` is a logical `or`. That means if one of the statements is true it enters the if clause.

So just change the last if for an else and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that last if statement- let's step through your use case there:

you enter `D`.

`isLetter('D')` is `true` so it prints

`isDigit('D')` is `false` so that doesn't print

`!isLetter('D') && !isDigit('D')` is the same as

`! true || ! false` (evaluating the method calls) which is the same as
`false || true` (evaluating the `!`'s) which is the same as
`true` (evaluating the `||`) so it prints.

To fix it, you can change your `||` to `&&`, or put back the `else` clause you have commented out. I personally think the `else` clause is a better solution because it clearly communicates your idea that what's not a letter and not a digit must be a symbol without having to explicitly check for each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Character.isLetter(letter) || !Character.isDigit(letter))
```

You used OR instead of AND, so letter "D" will pass when you check for `!Character.isDigit(letter)`

In the last if statement, change the || to  &&.